# Organize data by ID then by Date and find difference in R

Tags: r

I am trying to organize a large amount of data first by unique ID, then by Date in order to find the difference day over day.

An example of my data is shown below:

```
date        id       value1    value2
1/1/2019   1234       10         12
1/2/2019   1234       11         14
1/3/2019   1234       12         15
1/1/2019   9876       9          10
1/2/2019   9876       11         12
1/3/2019   9876       6          9
```

What I would like to accomplish is to find the difference between dates for a given ID. An example of the output column would look as follows:

```
date        id       value1    value2    difference       change
1/1/2019   1234       10         12          0              0
1/2/2019   1234       11         14         11-12          -1/12
1/3/2019   1234       12         15         12-14          -2/14
1/1/2019   9876       9          10          0              0
1/2/2019   9876       11         12         11-10           1/10
1/3/2019   9876       6          9           6-12          -6/12
```

Questions: First how do I sort the data by ID then by Date? Second, how do I calculate the difference for each following date for a given ID?

Thanks!

Comment: see my updated answer according to your post updates

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do a group by 'id' and get the `diff` of 'value'

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- df1 %>%
          group_by(id) %>%
          mutate(difference = c(0, diff(value)))
df1
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   id [2]
#  date        id value difference
#  <chr>    <int> <int>      <dbl>
#1 1/1/2019  1234    10          0
#2 1/2/2019  1234    11          1
#3 1/3/2019  1234    12          1
#4 1/1/2019  9876     9          0
#5 1/2/2019  9876    11          2
#6 1/3/2019  9876     6         -5
```

Here the 'date' is already `arrange`d, if, not, then do `arrange` after converting to `Date` class (assuming the format is day-month-year)

```
library(lubridate)
df1 %>%
   arrange(id, dmy(date)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(difference = c(0, diff(value)))
```

#### Update

With the new dataset, after grouping by 'id',  we can get the difference between the current element of 'value1' with the  `lag` of  'value2' and get the `change` by dividing the 'difference' column with the `lag` column

```
df2 %>%
   arrange(id, dmy(date)) %>%
   group_by(id) %>%
   mutate(lagvalue2 = lag(value2, default = first(value1))) %>%
   ungroup %>%
   mutate(difference = value1  - lagvalue2, 
          change = difference/lagvalue2) %>%
   select(-lagvalue2)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
#  date        id value1 value2 difference  change
#  <chr>    <int>  <int>  <int>      <int>   <dbl>
#1 1/1/2019  1234     10     12          0  0     
#2 1/2/2019  1234     11     14         -1 -0.0833
#3 1/3/2019  1234     12     15         -2 -0.143 
#4 1/1/2019  9876      9     10          0  0     
#5 1/2/2019  9876     11     12          1  0.1   
#6 1/3/2019  9876      6      9         -6 -0.5
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df2)[order(dmy(date)), lagvalue2 := shift(value2, fill = first(value1)) , id]
df2[, difference := value1 - lagvalue2][, change := difference/lagvalue2]
```

---

In `base R` we can do

```
df1 <- df1[order(df1$id, as.Date(df1$date, "%d/%m/%Y")),]
df1$difference <- with(df1, ave(value, id, FUN = function(x) c(0, diff(x))))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(date = c("1/1/2019", "1/2/2019", "1/3/2019", "1/1/2019", 
"1/2/2019", "1/3/2019"), id = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 9876L, 9876L, 
9876L), value = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 6L)), class = "data.frame", 
row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))



df2 <- structure(list(date = c("1/1/2019", "1/2/2019", "1/3/2019", "1/1/2019", 
"1/2/2019", "1/3/2019"), id = c(1234L, 1234L, 1234L, 9876L, 9876L, 
9876L), value1 = c(10L, 11L, 12L, 9L, 11L, 6L), value2 = c(12L, 
14L, 15L, 10L, 12L, 9L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

Comment: Really great answer! Thank you. 
What if I were to want to find the difference between two columns? One in "value1" and one in "value2"?

Comment: @HonnSolo   In that case, you don't need a group_by.  after the `arrange` just do `mutate(difference = value1  - value2)`

Comment: Well what if the difference is value2[2,x] - value1[1,y]? In other words, they are still solving across rows, but now it is also across columns.

Comment: @HonnSolo  In that case, after the `group_by(id) %>% mutate_at(vars(starts_with('value')), ~ c(0, diff(.)))`

Comment: Okay, I edited my post above slightly to provide a better insight into what I am doing. In reality it is calculating my change in bid/ask positions day over day for a time series of options (don't know if that is helpful). What I want to know is, what is my change in value between value1 at time t+1 versus value2 at time t+0 over value2 at time t+0.

Comment: Excellent and extremely fast code. Really great answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is base R solution to make it, which uses `split()` + `Map()` + `rbind()`:

```
dfout <- do.call(rbind, c(make.row.names = F,
                       Map(function(v) cbind(x <- v[order(as.Date(v$date,"%d/%m/%Y")),],
                                             difference = c(0,x$value1[-1] - x$value2[-nrow(x)]),
                                             change = c(0,x$value1[-1] - x$value2[-nrow(x)])/c(1,x$value2[-nrow(x)])), 
                           split(df,df$id))))
```

such that

```
> dfout
      date   id value1 value2 difference      change
1 1/1/2019 1234     10     12          0  0.00000000
2 1/2/2019 1234     11     14         -1 -0.08333333
3 1/3/2019 1234     12     15         -2 -0.14285714
4 1/1/2019 9876      9     10          0  0.00000000
5 1/2/2019 9876     11     12          1  0.10000000
6 1/3/2019 9876      6      9         -6 -0.50000000
```